# Crackme assistance - unknown function

Tags: assembly, x86, decompilation, dll, crackme

i have a problem about a crackme that my friend sent me for a bet. I solved most of it but i am stuck with this function. I can't even understand what the function is trying to do. Please help.

images related to my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjhVN.jpg

Comment: Really, you should post more detail

Comment: what else should i add please say something

Comment: I think the most helpful way is to send the binary

Comment: Hello there you go this is the file, it might have a virus by the way so be careful,btw file changed a bit my friend send me a second one after i couldn't make the first one(and im dxAhax) https://easyupload.io/1qb31x

Comment: No, i think its a lol loader can you do something ? I didn't have enough information for reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a crackme, 27MB is quite large and the strings seem to indicate that this is possibly related to League of Legends.

Comment: Cracking LoL for a bet?